# Add a new attribute to existing product type - SAP Hybris e-Commerce

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to add a new attribute called 'url_key' to the existing product type created by Hybris on initialization just for learning purposes.

I had created my item type in my extension like this:

```
<itemtype code="UrlKeyProduct" extends="Product" generate="false">
    <attributes>
        <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="url_key" type="java.lang.String">
            <persistence type="property"/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true" optional="true" unique="true"/>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

Compiled, and now I see a UrlKeyProductModel.java and a GeneratedUrlKeyProductModel.java... but what to do now to have this new attribute available on the product cockpit when creating/updating a product and also in my OCC response through REST?

I saw references to several xml files like editorArea, but I don't know if these files already exists or do I have to create them or where.

Any thanks appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done now:

- You have created a new model calls **UrlKeyProduct** which extends the normal **Product**.
- The **UrlKeyProduct** model has all the abilities that the **Product** Model has and also have the attribute **url_key**

Now you have to create a **UrlKeyProduct_editorArea.xml** in the specific cockpit folder to modify what you want to see in the cockpit, when you select it. I would copy all the stuff from the **Product_editorArea.xml** and than also add your new attribute.

But to be honest, this is really the basics of hybris. So I think you should definitly do the **Core Developer Train** to understand the fundamentals of hybris.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a very open ended question. First, step would be to do the core developer training and do the trails on the wiki. There are also a number of similar questions you can find on the experts forum e.g. https://experts.hybris.com/questions/1989/custom-attribute-not-visible-in-basic-area-in-prod.html